# Django query to count data using starts with for year matching

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filter

In Django, I am querying for the year count. but when I run the below query it is not returning the exact result. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here can anyone please help
me or suggested me the solution to?

```
 date_list = ['2022','2023']
 
 def yearly data(date_list, qFilter):
    all_dict = []
    for i in range(0,len(date_list)):
        week_list = date_list[i]
        count = Stats.objects.filter(Q(StartDate__startswith = week_list) & Q(Server__startswith = qFilter)).values('StartDate').annotate(dcount=Count('StartDate'))
        all_dict.append({"date" : date_list[i], "count" : count})
    return all_dict
```

As a result I am getting the below output:

```
[{'date': 2022, 'count': <QuerySet [{'StartDate': '2022-03-01', 'dcount': 1}]>}, 
{'date': 2023, 'count': <QuerySet [{'StartDate': '2023-01-09', 'dcount': 50},
{'StartDate': '2023-01-23', 'dcount': 89},
{'StartDate': '2023-02-12', 'dcount': 3}, {'StartDate': '2023-02-22', 'dcount': 37}, {'StartDate': '2023-03-01', 'dcount': 1}]>}]
```

Expected result:

```
[{'date': 2022, 'count': <QuerySet [{'Year': '2022', 'dcount': 1}]>}, 
{'date': 2023, 'count': <QuerySet [{'Year': '2023', 'dcount': 10}]>}]
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: please share model code

Answer (score 0):

You should aggregate, not annotate:

```
date_list = ['2022', '2023']


def yearly_data(date_list, qFilter):
    return [
        {
            'date': y,
            'count': Stats.objects.filter(
                StartDate__year=y, Server__startswith=qFilter
            ).count(),
        }
        for y in date_list
    ]
```

Comment: Solution is not working

Comment: @Nehanegi: what is not working? Can you share the `Stats` model?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
from datetime import datetime

    def yearly_data(date_list, qFilter):
        all_dict = []
        for year in date_list:
            year_start = datetime.strptime(year, '%Y')
            year_end = year_start.replace(year=year_start.year+1)
            count = Stats.objects.filter(
                Q(StartDate__gte=year_start) &
                Q(StartDate__lt=year_end) &
                Q(Server__startswith=qFilter)
            ).values('Year').annotate(dcount=Count('StartDate'))
            all_dict.append({"date" : int(year), "count" : list(count)})
        return all_dict
```

output:

```
[{'date': 2022, 'count': [{'Year': '2022', 'dcount': 1}]}, 
 {'date': 2023, 'count': [{'Year': '2023', 'dcount': 10}]}]
```

Comment: I tried but the same output is coming.

Comment: [{'date': 2022, 'count': <QuerySet [{'StartDate': '2022-03-01', 'dcount': 1}]>}, {'date': 2023, 'count': <QuerySet [{'StartDate': '2023-01-09', 'dcount': 50}, {'StartDate': '2023-01-23', 'dcount': 89}, {'StartDate': '2023-02-12', 'dcount': 3}, {'StartDate': '2023-02-22', 'dcount': 37}, {'StartDate': '2023-03-01', 'dcount': 1}]>}]